How do you get `navigate` to update `useParams` hook values?
In React, I have a browser route that is effectively:
<Route path="some/entity/:objectId?" element={<MyComponent />} />

That maps to a functional MyComponent, which uses the useParams hook to get the value of the optional objectId like so:
const { objectId } = useParams();

Now, in one of my events, I use the navigate object (via the useNavigate hook) to update the object ID part of the URL like so:
const navigate = useNavigate();
[... later in some event handler ...]
const newObjectId = [...];
navigate(`/some/entity/${newObjectId}`);

The URL gets updated. However, my component does not get the new objectId through the useParams hook. It still has the old value. How do I fix this?

The route path parameter value should update on its own. Are you sure objectId didn't update? Or is more likely the case you've some logic that depends on this objectId value and that didn't update? Can you [edit] to clarify the exact specific problem you face, and share a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with?

Sure enough, you are right. There was another factor at play. Thank you! (Just knowing it was SUPPOSED to work is helpful. I wasn't sure.)
